# Get RAM and CPU usage for process in Linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux

I want to write a program like system monitor.
I want to have a list of programs with their process ID and usage of CPU and RAM.
I know Linux writes this information in the `/proc` folder but somebody told me that I can use some functions to get it too.  For example a program that will return a list like:

```
name  PID   RAM
sh    3904  72KIB
```

And I want to code in C++.

Comment: There a MANY programs out there already that do this. Most are open source. Go look at the source code.

Comment: @Chris could you please help me an give me a link?thanks

Comment: [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) is a personal favorite of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you look at the source code for `top`, which displays these and many more process statistics?

[Here](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/procps/top.c) is the busybox version, which is comparatively short and simple.  It gets the information by reading the `proc` filesystem, that logic is [here](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/procps.c#n285).

Comment: thanks...it seems good.but can i how can i use it?it seems it is not standard library.could you please help me a bit?

Comment: @mimad: you can read pseudo-files from the Linux `/proc/` filesystem using the standard library. To enumerate files there, use e.g. Boost.