# Get system memory and CPU usage from within C++11 code

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, memory, cpu-usage

How can I get the total percentage or volume of memory usage and CPU consumption from within C++11 code on ubuntu (or any other linux-based system)?

The usage I want to get is for the whole system, not just for current thread or process.

Comment: What have you tried? There is no way of doing this using the features of Standard C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I tried to google and didn't find a sufficient answer :) also, I don't need to use standard c++, I just need to do it on linux system using some linux-specific system info files presumably

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166/608639), [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/479722/608639), [Get RAM and CPU usage for process in Linux with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6659460/608639), [How to get total CPU usage in Linux using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3017162/608639), [How to get memory usage at runtime using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669438/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and use `/proc/meminfo`. You can open it and read it as a sequential file (even if it often behaves as a pipe; e.g. it is not seekable).

Of course, this is Linux specific.

And you might scan the `/proc/`  directory (using [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), `closedir`) for directories starting with a digit, and read each of their `/proc/1234/maps` or `/proc/1234/status` - these correspond to process 1234)

Read also [linuxatemyram](http://linuxatemyram.com/)